# django template string - replace line break with line space

Tags: django, string, replace, django-templates, newline

I have a string in my django1.4 template that I want to replace the line breaks with a whitespace. I only want to replace the line breaks with a single white space in the template string.

So far all my searces on django docs, Google and SO have not given me an answer.

Here is my string in my template:

```
{{ education_detail.education_details_institution_name|safe|truncatechars:20|striptags }}
```

When I have the following string saved:

```
University
Bachelor of Something
2008 - 2010
```

The string in the django template is rendered as:

```
UniversityB...
```

I want to replace the line break with a space between the yB like so:

```
University B...
```

How would I do this?

Comment: Have you had a look at [`truncatechars_html`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#truncatechars-html)? I think this could be used instead the `|safe|truncatechars`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the custom filter code that I finally got operational:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter(name='replace_linebr')
def replace_linebr(value):
    """Replaces all values of line break from the given string with a line space."""
    return value.replace("<br />", ' ')
```

Here is the call on the template:

```
{{ education_detail.education_details_institution_name|replace_linebr }}
```

I hope that this will help somebody else.

Answer (score 2):

You can rely on built-in [`truncatechars`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#truncatechars) filter's behavior to replace newlines with spaces. All you need is to pass a [`length`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#length) of the string as an argument, so that you would not see your string shortened:

```
{% with value|length as length %}
    {{ value|truncatechars:length }}
{% endwith %}
```

This is a bit hacky, but uses only built-in filters.

You can always write a [custom filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/) if you need this kind of functionality to be reusable.

Comment: I'm using `truncatechars_html:40` and still have line breaks